# create collision in wireless m2m network and simulate the packet dropping in omnett++

Tags: networking, omnet++

scenario :i need to simulate a collision within a m2m network with one server, 2 gateways and each gateway having 5 node hierarchically connected. the simulation should show the packet being dropped when packet from nodes through gateway arrive at server at same time and analyse the dropped packet for delay and reliability.

question :
 1.how do i simultaneously sent the packet from gateway to server at same time?
2.how do show in simulation the packet being dropped?
3.how to show the collision happened inside the server ?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: omnet++ is a simulation tool like ns2, an open source one. this question is purely on the basis of programming part. i am doing a simulation project with this tool using an architecture mentioned in scenario.